# About the group of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm stuck at this section of the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ be a subset of $R$, with $S$ multiplicatively closed.
>
> Find the group of units of $S^{-1}R$.

My try:

> $U(S^{-1}R)=\{\frac{a}{b}\mid a,b\in S\}$.

Is it correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you can show that if $S$ has zero divisors then $S^{-1}R$ is trivial.  Then the units are the ratios where the numerator and denominator are not zero-divisors.  Something like that should work.

Comment: Hi @GregoryGrant. $S$ has not zero divisors because is multiplicatively closed.

Comment: @user215565 $S=R$ is multiplicatively closed, but it has zero divisors if $R$ does.

Comment: @user215565 As Slade says, multiplicatively closed does not imply no zero-divisors.

Comment: @Slade on my notes I have that $S$ is multiplicatively closed if $1\in S$, $a,b\in S \implies ab\in S$, $0$ is not in $S$ and $S$ has not zero divisors.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense because the relation as you stated it is *not* an equivalence relation unless you assume $S$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: @GregoryGrant exactly, we had to prove it before that section of finding the group of units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gregory pointed out, $U(S^{-1}R)$ is defined as follows: $$U(S^{-1}R)=\Big\{\frac{a}{b}\in S^{-1}R \mid \text{$a$ is either in $S$ or a unit in $R$, and $b \in S$}\Big\}.$$

HINT: Furthermore, you can conclude that, if $r\in U(R)$, then $i(r)=\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}$, and exists an element of $R$, let's name it $s$, such that $r\cdot s=s \cdot r=1$. So the inverse will be $\displaystyle\frac{s}{1}$.

Can you conclude the last one?

Answer (score 2):

Just ask yourself what's the condition for $a/s\in S^{-1}R$ (where $a\in R$ and $s\in S$) for being invertible: you have to find $b/t\in S^{-1}R$, with $b\in R$ and $t\in S$ such that $(ab)/(st)=1/1$, that is, $ab=st$.

Suppose $a/s$ is invertible; then
$$
a\in \hat{S}=\{x\in R:xy\in S\text{ for some }y\in R\}
$$
Conversely, suppose $a\in\hat{S}$; then we have $ab\in S$, for some $b\in R$; then
$$
\frac{a}{s}\frac{bs}{ab}=\frac{1}{1}
$$
So
$$
U(S^{-1}R)=\left\{\frac{a}{s}: a\in\hat{S}, s\in S\right\}
$$

The set $\hat{S}$ is often called the *saturation* of $S$ and it's not difficult to prove that $\hat{S}$ is multiplicatively closed and that the canonical homomorphism
$$
S^{-1}R\to\hat{S}^{-1}R
$$
is an isomorphism. However, the sets $S$ and $\hat{S}$ can differ; if $S=\hat{S}$, then $S$ is said to be *saturated*. The complement of a prime ideal (or, more generally, the complement of a union of prime ideals) is saturated.

Actually, the hypothesis that $S$ does not contain zero divisors is redundant (but the equivalence relation used for defining the quotient ring is defined in a slightly different way).

Comment: Hi @egreg. Why do you say conversely? What statement were you proving? Thank you.

Comment: @user215565 First I prove that, if $a/s$ is invertible, then $a\in\hat{S}$; after this I prove the converse: if $a\in\hat{A}$, then $a/s$ is invertible (for all $s\in S$).

Answer (score 0):

The units are the things of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ is either an element of $S$ or a unit in $R$ and $b\in S$.

Comment: I think that he only possibility for $a$ is to be in $S$. You're taking pairs from $R \times S$, so $a$ must to be in $S$. Why can $a$ be a unit in $R$ and not to be in $S$?